# Настройка сочетаний клавиш в ipython notebook

Tags: python, api, jupyter-notebook

Задача следующая: в *ipython notebook* необходимо добавить сочетание клавиш для конкретного действия из меню.

Например, требуется назначить клавиши для перемещения ячейки вниз и вверх.

В справке, показываемой в *ipython notebook* по кнопке <kbd>H</kbd>, сочетания клавиш для этих действий не обнаружено. Найденное в интернете сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd> не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если требуется добавить новое сочетание клавиш для какого-либо действия в `ipython-notebook`, достаточно добавить соответствующую запись в файл `<profile>/static/custom/custom.js` своего [профиля](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html#python-config-files), где `<profile>` - это путь к настройкам  профиля ipython.

---

По умолчанию `ipython` запускается под стандартным профилем, настройки которого обычно расположены по адресу `~/.ipython/profile_default/`.

---

Открываем соответствующий файл `custom.js` в любом редакторе и добавляем действие при загрузке `ipython notebook` (для примера назначим клавиши `Shift-j` и `Shift-k` командам "опустить ячейку" и "поднять ячейку" соответственно):

```js
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function() {
    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut(
            'shift-j', 
            'ipython.move-selected-cell-down');

    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut(
            'shift-k', 
            'ipython.move-selected-cell-up');
});
```

В первой строке мы добавили анонимную функцию, которая будет запущена при старте `ipython notebook`.

В ней происходит добавление двух сочетаний клавиш для стандартных действий с помощью метода `add_shortcut` объекта `IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts`.

В метод `add_shortcut` в простейшем случае передаются две строки. Первая соответствует сочетанию клавиш, а вторая отвечает за действие по этому сочетанию.

---

Объект `IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts` отвечает за сочетания клавиш в командном режиме. Если требуется добавить сочетание в режим редактирования, используйте объект `IPython.keyboard_manager.edit_shortcuts`

Список всех стандартных действий (и соответствующих им строк) я нашёл только [в исходном коде `jupyter`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/notebook/js/actions.js#L38). Важно помнить, что названия стандартных действий должны иметь префикс `ipython.`, как в примере выше.

Как я понял, отсутствие официальной документации [аргументируется](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276770/where-do-i-find-the-javascript-api-docs-for-window-ipython#comment46808892_29276770) тем, что IPython JavaScript API постоянно изменяется.

---

Также существует расширенное создание действий на сочетание клавиш: вторым аргументом функции `add_shortcut` вместо строки можно передать объект со следующими полями:

- `help`: строка, которая будет показываться в справке по всем сочетаниям клавиш.
- `help_index`: строка (по умолчанию `zz`), в соответствии с которой осуществляется сортировка сочетаний клавиш в справке.
- `handler`: функция, принимающая один аргумент (объект `event`), описывающая действие по сочетанию клавиш.
  Если эта функция возвращает `false`, то обработка сочетания клавиш будет на этом завершена, а также не будет вызвана обработка по умолчанию (обычно и возвращают `false`). Подробнее в документации по обработке событий jQuery.

Посмотрим на примере, как это выглядит:

```js
IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.add_shortcut('shift-j', {
    help : 'move cell down',
    help_index : 'zz',
    handler : function(event) {
        IPython.notebook.move_cell_down();
        return false;
    }}
);
```

Это второй, известный мне, и более общий способ добавить действие по сочетанию клавиш.

---

Источники:

- [Определение списка стандартных действий в исходном коде программы](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/notebook/js/actions.js#L38)
- [Справка по созданию своих действий на сочетания клавиш](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/User%20Interface.ipynb#Keyboard-shortcut-customization)
- [Реализация стандартных действий в исходном коде программы](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/notebook/js/notebook.js#L385)
- [Добавление сочетаний клавиш в исходном коде программы](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/static/base/js/keyboard.js#L344)
- [Небольшая статья о JavaScript API для ipython notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/kikocorreoso/PyConES14_talk-Hacking_the_Notebook/blob/master/notebooks/05-Manipulating_with_js.ipynb)